# How to run a Desktop graphical application just once under sudo?

Tags: gui, sudo

For example, I'm trying to run Archive Manager from Ubuntu Desktop (10.04) under sudo otherwise it won't let me extract a Software Development Kit into /usr/local

**Update:** I don't want sudo to be a permanent change to launching the application; only to run it under sudo when I choose, until it's quit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can run the software from the command-line/terminal with `gksudo` prefixed to the command,  which will present the prompt for your sudoer's password prior to launching.

```
gksudo file-roller
```

Though you mentioned you do not want to make this a permanent change - you could add a new Menu item into something like `Applications` -> `System Tools` via `alacarte` (`System` -> `Preferences` -> `Main Menu`) The command for which could be `gksudo file-roller` creating both a regular Archive Manager launcher and a "root" Archive Manager launcher - for convenience.

Comment: That's beautiful with the gksudo GUI prompt version. Also I like the idea of creating a second set of menu commands for gksudo'd items. Thanks!

Comment: Alternatively you can use the alt+f2 dialog and enter `gksudo file-roller`

Answer (score 2):

Check out the package `nautilus-gksu`. After installing and restarting your session (or just nautilus) you'll be able to right-click on any file/folder and select "Open as administrator" and be prompted for your password. Works well for opening root nautilus windows, root archive managers, root text editors... you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

I've added a Nautilus script that allows me to - from nautilus - open the current folder as root. That way, I could open the current folder as root, right-click and extract the archive using Archive manager and then move the files to /usr/local. When done, I just close the root-nautilus; no permanent change is done, and no need for the command-line.

/N

Comment: Is is this one? http://g-scripts.sourceforge.net/nautilus-scripts/Execute/Misc/root-nautilus-here

Comment: Yup, that's the one!